# GCMRegistrar vs GoogleCloudMessaging which to use?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Another one of my stupid questions probably.

I am confused on which to use GCMRegistrar or GoogleCloudMessaging, i know that GCMRegistrar is deprecated and i want to use GoogleCloudMessaging API but the problem is i can't find the jar files for it. so if you could help me by giving me jar file for the new GoogleCloudMessaging API it would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html have you tried taking a look here

Comment: where is the jar file? how can i download and use it? oh by the way when i install GCM in android sdk manager and go for extras>google>gcm>gcmclient i only see GCMRegistrar jar not the new one

Comment: Just one comment regarding this topic: I have an entire app developed using GCMRegistrar. Should I upgrade the implementation to use the Google Play Services? Is there any problem continuing using the GCM library?

Comment: @RenatoLochetti at the moment google is still supporting GCMRegistrar and like all other deprecated functions it will also cease to function in may be one year or sooner. so its better to upgrade it. sorry for the late reply

Comment: 2016 update: GCMRegistrar is still working for us, we use it with Azure Notification Hubs.  It is a small lib (14KB) and lets us avoid GoogleCloudMessaging dependencies.  Your mileage may vary!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because GCM before was a library, now it's part of the Google Play Services. So to use it you will need to follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and download and include the Google Play services on your project using [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

You are welcome :)

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful!
Cheers

Comment: buddy i accepted the answer but i have one more question if u don't mind! i have an app and i want a feature in it that will check whether google play services is installed on the device or not? is it possible?

Comment: Create another question and link it here, so we will help another people with the same question :) Let me know when you create it

Comment: actually that question asked many times in here so i got the answer and i think if i create a new question ill be pounded with negative points :P

Comment: **The requested URL was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes gcm.jar is deprecated. But I didn't find good explanation "why"! GCMRegistrar was good helper class. When you look at its sources you'll find that it's almost the same as example code of (now preferred) GoogleCloudMessaging API. So Google wants everyone to write (or copy) again and again the same code into all projects using GCM? Or shall every developer create his/her own helper class, a GCMRegistrar alike?

On the other hand when I use Google Play Services library, I use a library with a lot of ballast I don't need, I need just GCM, I'm not interested in other services.

Why don't they create a library for each service? GCM, Maps, Ads, Wallet, ... so every developer can include only what he needs.

Google's approach is far from optimization. I want to create as small and fast apps as possible. Google obviously doesn't. :-(

Answer (score 0):

gcm.jar is deprecated.
Use GoogleCloudMessaging. comes with GooglePlayServices Library.

SDK Manager > Extras > Google Play Services.

then import google play services library PROJECT : Right Click > Properties >Android > Add...

and the project is in C:...\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

UNCHECK "Is Library"